# Closing a Kendo window using close button

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I am opening a kendo window (a cshtml view) from an asp.net application. I am opening this using a div like this from the aspx page.

```
<div id="comments"></div>
```

Within the window Want to close it using a button. I am using below javascript function to close it on button click.

```
function CloseWindow() {
    $("#comments").data("kendoWindow").close();
}
```

But i am getting following error:

VM3356:18 `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'close')`

Answer (score 0):

```
function CloseWindow() {
    $("#comments").data("kendoWindow").close();
}
```

in this code you try to close the **div**, not the **kendo window**

you should give a name or id attribute to your kendo window element like this

```
@(Html.Kendo().Window().Scrollable(false)
                      .Name("sampleWindow").Title("Window").Visible(true)
                      .Actions(actions => actions.Close()).Modal(true).Draggable(true)
                      .Height(530).Width(800)
                      .Events(events => events.Refresh("RefreshWindow"))
    )
```

above i gave sampleWindow name to the kendo window

so function will be like this

```
 function CloseWindow() {
    $("#sampleWindow").data("kendoWindow").close();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function CloseWindow() {
   if(kendo.widgetInstance($("#comments")) != undefined)
      $("#comments").data("kendoWindow").close();
   }
}
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.